# Vue.js doesn't display brackets like {{ post.title }}

Tags: vue.js, jekyll, vuejs2

For some reason Vue doesn't render `{{post.title}}`, `{{ post.content }}` brackets for me. The content is empty (look at the rendered html below), but `v-bind:href="post.url"` works for some reason. I'm new to Vue.js and really stuck for day now. 
Backstory:
this code is Vue instant search for my Jekyll blog.

**HTML**

```
<div v-if="articles" class="large-12 columns">  
    <article v-for="post in itemsSearched" class="article-summary">
      <header>
        <h2><a v-bind:href="post.url">{{post.title}}</a></h2>
      </header>      
      <p>{{ post.content }}</p>      
      <div class="large-12 column">
        <a class="read-more" v-bind:href="post.url">Read More...</a>
        <div class="middle_line"></div>
      </div>
    </article>      
</div>
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
<article class="article-summary">
    <header>
        <h2><a href="/jekyll-update/2017/05/23/welcome-to-jekyll.html"></a></h2>
    </header> 
    <p></p> 
    <div class="large-12 column">
        <a href="/jekyll-update/2017/05/23/welcome-to-jekyll.html" class="read-more">Read More...</a> 
        <div class="middle_line"></div>
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/templates/) uses [double curly braces](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/introduction/) itself, so you need to define custom [delimiters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters) for your Vue.

```
new Vue({
    delimiters:['<%', '%>'],
    ....
})
```

And then use

```
<% post.title %>
```

Instead.

You can define whatever delimiters you want, I just used those as an example.

Answer (score 3):

Please use `v-text` or `v-html` instead. In vue 2.0,`Vue-config-delimiters` was deprecated, `delimiters` is only avaliable in the full build.[]:https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Vue-config-delimiters-replaced